# Modify Column In Snowflake Table to a clustering key

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Needs to update a column to a clustering key,trying these but not working:

```
 <ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS "TABLE" MODIFY COLUMN ID  SET CLUSTER BY (ID)>
  `ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS "TABLE" MODIFY COLUMN ID  CLUSTER BY (ID)`
```

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE "TABLE" CLUSTER BY (ID);
```

Related:
[Changing the Clustering Key for a Table](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-clustering-keys.html#changing-the-clustering-key-for-a-table)